# Encrypt Get-Parameter(URL) Tomcat/Servlet

Tags: url, servlets, encryption, get

is there a possibility to encrypt or just don't display the Get Parameters in the Internetbrowser when im using JavaServlets on Tomcat?

that means for example:  localhost/main?id=3
should be displayed like this:  localhost/main    or  localhost/main?6puu4YjzScxHsv9t....

Is there a simple and fast solution? Does this make sense?

Thx for your tips..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use POST instead of GET on your HTML form. This will turn `localhost/main?id=3` into `localhost/main`. The parameter `id` will still be passed and you should be able to retrieve its value in the same way, on the server-side.

Comment: Yes thx i'm using post in forms.. but im using the getparameters to redirect to the same servlet with a link.

for example servlet index  contains a link index?show=2 if you click it it shows other data

Comment: @JannisHanke Hmmm... you cannot do this with an `<a href="...">someLink</a>` but you could use CSS to make a button look like a hyperlink. That way you can pass `show` as a POST parameter.

Comment: is there another solution? i see all the time java webpages where u never see a getparameter behind the urlstring.. 
how do they solve a redirect over link?

Comment: Maybe they've stored the parameters as session variables. This is quite common in web development. Another way to disguise URLs is to add URL Rewrite rules in the web proxy.

Comment: Okay thanks i'll get some information about url rewrite... thank you